# Shiny does not give me a proper histogram in R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to generate a histogram using rnorm() and then animated it. I have used the following codes:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel("sample"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1,
                max = 2000, 
                value = 500)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    hist(rnorm(input$obs))

  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and I get the following error

> Error in dnorm: Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> [No stack trace available]

I tried to make it a numeric and I did not get the plot properly.

Comment: Your code works for me. (although you have not assigned `server` and `ui` in the code chunk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like @Croote said: it works fine, but you haven't assigned `ui` and `server` in your code. Therefore:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  
  headerPanel("sample"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1,
                max = 2000, 
                value = 500)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
    
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```